# All comments for my post are gone except one

Tags: support

Recently I posted answer to a question and apparently someone didn't liked it and left a lengthy note. I responded and asked what's wrong and how do you think it should be.  After few comments, I see that all of comments vanished except one. I'm wondering what is policy of deleting comments and without leaving any trail?

I'm not sure if I'm in violation of terms, but link to post is here. [Mongo convert embedded document to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164746/mongo-convert-embedded-document-to-array?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Sometimes, reasonable comments just get caught in the net while the mods are trawling up all the rubbish.

Comment: Nothing of value was lost. Comments that were bickering were deleted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker got it. I was wondering what happened. Appreciated for educating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the comments that were deleted:

[image]

Comments should posted when you're asking for clarification for a post or making some sort of addendum (which you should then edit into the answer if it's really that useful).  Comments that are made for any other purpose (or even the purposes I listed above) are subject to deletion at any time.

In this case, these comments were simply two users fighting; and no one was served by them staying around.

Comment: Appreciated George. I was bashed for obviously no reason and even without looking at context and what's there. now my question is, is there way to at least ask for moderation when someone post discouraging comments for sake of comments?

Comment: @Saleem if you hover to the left of a comment you'll see a little flag icon. If you click that you can then choose a reason as to why you're flagging that comment.